# Android SAX parsing &amp as new line

Tags: android, xml, rss, sax, saxparser

I have implemented a XML parser that parses a RSS Feed in Android using SAX Parses. The RSS feed contains &amp. unfortunately the parser seems to create new newlines.

So `"Hello &amp Goodbye"` becomes

```
"Hello
&
 Goodbye"
```

Is there some encoding I need to set?

This is the Parser class :

```
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

            XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();
            reader.setContentHandler(handler);
            InputSource is = new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream());
            reader.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser is entitled to break the content of a text node anywhere, and pass it to the application in multiple calls of characters. Many parsers choose to break the node at entity boundaries. I suspect you are getting the text in multiple chunks and adding the newline from your application.